# Is the discrete metric equivalent to the d1 metric on R2?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is the discrete metric equivalent to the d1 metric (the taxicab metric) on R2? Metrics are defined to be equivalent if we can show that if we have an open ball around point x in one metric, we can find an open ball in the other metric that is contained by the first open ball.

In this specific case, I think the metrics cannot be equivalent because for the discrete metric, all open balls less than radius one, we just have the singleton element, but no singleton element is open under the d1 metric. Is the reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, they are different for the reason you stated. However, it does require some proof that singleton elements aren’t open in d1.